# Conditional logic in Rails/ActionMailer for two versions of same article to readers/subscribers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, conditional-statements, email

Users are either readers or subscribers. When a new article is published, subscribers get a full text e-mail, readers get a teaser text. Assuming scopes in the model for readers/subscribers, is this right or do I need another conditional for each type of user?

```
if @article.valid?
  User.subscribers.each do |user|
    ArticleMailer.send_article_full(@article, user).deliver_now
  end
  User.readers.each do |user|
    ArticleMailer.send_article_teaser(@article, user).deliver_now
  end
  redirect_to :root, notice: "Article sent"
else
  render :new, notice: "There was an error"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact, every user can either be a reader or subscriber, but can't be both simultaneously, and if you have correct scopes defined for `readers` and `subscribers` in the `User` model, then it should be fine. You don't need another conditional for each type of user because that would be redundant.

Comment: Right, thank you K M. I've been playing around with it this week and it works. The current versions have an extra scope for "wants e-mail", to weed out those users who don't first: `User.wantsarticles.readers.each do |user|`. There's perhaps another issue now with running the background job, but I'll ask that in another question.

Comment: Here's the [next, related, question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219759/is-this-expected-behaviour-for-delayed-job-rails-and-mandrill) on this, about how Delayed Job processes it all.