# Is this expected behaviour for Delayed Job, Rails and Mandrill?

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, delayed-job, mandrill

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168657/conditional-logic-in-rails-actionmailer-for-two-versions-of-same-article-to-read/), which explains the origins of the logic in the controller, I have a question about background jobs with Delayed Job before pushing it to github and re-deploying.

The model and scopes work, the logic in the controller(s) works, the conditionals in the e-mail *text.erb* files work, users are either readers or subscribers and can set their e-mail preferences on their "My Account" page: [Articles & Updates, Just Articles, No E-mail, etc.]. Delayed Job is set up and processing it all in the background, making the front end nice and fast as always, and Mandrill SMTP is receiving it all correctly and sending out the e-mails in a speedy manner.

The main logic block in *article_controller* does this to send the right e-mails to the right users:

```
if @article.update(article_params) && @article.status == 'published' && @article.created_at.today?
    User.wantsarticles.editor.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.delay.send_article_full(@article, user)
    end
    User.wantsarticles.subscribers.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.delay.send_article_full(@article, user)
    end
    User.wantsarticles.readers.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.delay.send_article_teaser(@article, user)
    end
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'admin', notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :action => 'admin', notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
    end
```

Looking at the Rails and Delayed Jobs logs, though, with a test set of just a few users (5-10), when it cycles through the logic and decides three e-mails need to be sent out, Rails is doing three INSERT INTO the DJ table and DJ then does this for each one:

```
Job NewsitemMailer.send_article_full (id=21) RUNNING
Job NewsitemMailer.send_article_full (id=21) COMPLETED after 0.8950
```

And then when it has finished, it reports back with:

```
3 jobs processed at 0.9039 j/s, 0 failed
```

And in the Mandrill logs, each e-mail sent gets its own API "success/fail" entry.

So: is this correct/expected behaviour for Delayed Job? Should it be creating one job for each e-mail? Or processing them in a different way? Is this way of doing things going to break the server when we start doing X thousand instead of ten/three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the default behaviour of `delayed_job`. You have `ArticleMailer.delay` call 3 times and it queues them all and hence you see `3 jobs processed`.

I think, you should also look at `handle_asynchronously` feature of `delayed_job`.

Also, if you plan to process a huge number of emails, I would suggest you to explore other options such as [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd)

They are better than `delayed_job` when it comes to process a lot of jobs. `delayed_job` is simple and easy to setup, but can face performance issue in scale.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808351/delayed-jobs-vs-resque-vs-beanstalkd) to get an overview.

Comment: Thank you KM! Yes, it's just a simple set up to begin with, to get things going and learn how these things work. And we'll see what it does to the server. We will certainly look into the other options you mention for a bit later on.